# post_type=='post' does not exclude pages

Tags: wordpress, post, title

I have following problem in Wordpress. I have this code in function.php which should make posts title on frontend from Yoast SEO title. Code works, however it has also impact on pages.

```
    function set_my_seo_title($title, $id)
{
    global $post;
    $seo_title=get_post_meta($id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);         
    return ((!empty($seo_title)&&$post->post_type=='post') ? $seo_title : $title);
}

add_filter('the_title', 'set_my_seo_title', 15, 2);
```

The problem is with condition `post_type=='post'`. It looks like there is some bug in Wordpress, but may be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Rather than using `global $post`, you could try it using `$wp_query`...or better yet, just call `is_single( $id )`

Comment: you should consider using `pre_get_post`  or `wp_query()` .

Comment: Thanks guys. I have to admitt I am not so good developer ;-) Do you mind to post there your full code variants? I am sure that it will help also others with same issue. Thank you!